# Is there an event called by changing the count of items in the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there an event called by changing the count of items in the `recyclerview`?

I want to call function every time `recyclerview` items are added.

Comment: what you've done so far? creating your own method won't solve your problem?

Comment: @Shermano no!I used from `handler.postDelayed (handlerTask, 1000);` . To keep item count , but I think this is the wrong way!

Comment: Can you just edit your question with your code?

Comment: @Shermano The question was answered by Michael Krause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

It turns out I misunderstood the original question.  What was really asked is how to get notified when the underlying data in an Adapter has changed.

For this you could use a [RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver) in conjunction with RecyclerView.Adapter's [registerAdapterDataObserver(AdapterDataObserver observer)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#registerAdapterDataObserver(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)) method to register for changes in the underlying list data.

**Original Answer**:

Your [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) is backed by a [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) which owns the actual list of items being displayed.

If you change the backing list, you should call one of the `notifyXXX` methods on your adapter to notify your RecyclerView what has changed (and optionally where in the list the change happened.)

At the very least, you could call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter to tell your RecyclerView that something somewhere in the list has changed.  This can be expensive since you're not being specific about what changed, so the RecyclerView has to query the adapter for more information and potentially redraw its entire client area of items.

Something like:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
if (adapter != null) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Behind the scenes, the RecyclerView will call the [RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getitemcount) method on the Adapter to determine what the current item count is.

Comment: Could you please use the example code? I did not understand the answer

Comment: There are many examples out there.  Here's the [one provided by the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).  It just requires some reading.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. Unfortunately, apparently you did not notice my question. The answer you gave me is not suitble to my question.

Comment: You could use a [RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver.html) in conjunction with RecyclerView.Adapter's [registerAdapterDataObserver(AdapterDataObserver observer)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#registerAdapterDataObserver(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)) method to register for changes in the underlying list data.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help. That's exactly what I want

Comment: Please post the response you wrote in your comment in original response so that I can select your answer as the correct answer. Because otherwise, those who seek answers will be confused!

Comment: Michael Krause can you post this as an answer ?

Comment: @JuanM.Rivero Done.